# How to use LSAdapter in Ember?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My integration of LSAdapter looks like this:

**index.html**

```
...
<script src="lib/ember-1.6.1.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ember-data.js"></script>
<script src="lib/localstorage_adapter.js"></script>
<script src="src/app.js"></script>
...
```

**app.js**

```
...
App = Ember.Application.create();
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.LSSerializer.extend();
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.LSAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'My-Data'
});
App.ApplicationStore = DS.Store.extend({
    adapter: App.ApplicationAdapter
});
...
```

When I debug my`createRecord()` call it never goes to the `localstorage_adapter.js`, just the `createRecord()` implementation of `ember-data.js` is called. So the data is in-memory but never hits `localStorage`.

Am I missing anything not mentioned in the docs of LSAdapter or Ember-Data?

Comment: Could you please update your work in jsbin or jsfiddle so that we can understand and help you. Please post your query also here http://discuss.emberjs.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the persistence adapters work in the same way. You create a record in memory with `createRecord()`, and then persist it with `save()`.

```
// First create the record in memory
var myRecord = this.store.createRecord('model-name', {
  attribute1: 'value1',
  attribute2: 'value2'
});

// Then persist the record to storage
myRecord.save();
```

The docs have a great [walkthrough of building an app](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/) using Fixtures, and then they switch to the local storage adapter at the end. It's more or less a drop-in replacement and there's nothing specific to make it work with local storage. Check out the example on ["Accepting Edits"](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/accepting-edits/) to see how they are using `save()` to persist the record.

Comment: lol, I found the missing save() call myself 15 minutes ago. Is there a way for auto-save on creating a record?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is not. The way I think about it is that createRecord is instantiating the object and save is persisting it. It's pretty comment to want to do these separately. You can always chain save() onto the end of createRecord if you want it altogether.

Comment: Well if you create multiple records it's not common, yes... well, thank you anyways :)